# How to create different autobiographies on different SE sites?

Tags: support, profile-page

I know users who are active on both professional and hobby sites, and they would like to use different autobiographies (a.k.a., "About Me") for their profiles on each site.

Therefore: How can users associate a different autobiography with each associated account?

Comment: AFAIK you *can* have a per-site bio. You can even have a per-site avatar if you want. I was `@retailcoder` for the longest time on Stack Overflow, and `@MatsMug` on Code Review.

Comment: OK ... how?  I just tried editing my bio on Meta, and the change is appearing on my profile on every SE site where I have an associated account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a link in small prints just below the <kbd>Save Profile</kbd> button:

[image: customize your profile just on this community]

Comment: Ah ha.  Should have checked the fine print ;)  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using windows 10 @Mat?

Comment: @Tim I am, indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more verbose walkthrough for users who need it:

1. From any SE page (*but not on a site Meta page: that will take you to a different profile type!*), click at the top of the page where it shows your avatar, rep, and badge summary to get to your profile:
   [image: Click here for profile]
2. Click "Edit Profile & Settings":
   [image]
3. Make the changes you want just for that site, and at the *very bottom of the page* you should find and click this:
   [image]